# Using Multithread for progressbar (update status)

Tags: multithreading, powershell, winforms, progress-bar

I'm trying to do a progress bar in powershell. I did one example but when I ran my script, I have a freeze and my progressbar isn't update...

I have an idea who'll be to create a thread when the state of my progress bar is update and with multithread. I would like to link them (if the thread who show the progress bar in 30% come to 40%, a new thread is create but the older one is closed), actually when I run my script, I have two separate threads but I want to regroup and link them like that. I think the freeze problem won't exist after sa.

Is anyone have an idea?

There is my code:

```
$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$syncHash.Add("progress", $NewMultiThreadprogress)
$syncHash.ProgressBar = $syncHash.progress
$processRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$processRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$processRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"          
$processRunspace.Open()
$processRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)   

$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
#Ouvre une nouvelle fenêtre.
$formA = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$formA.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$formA.text = "ProgressBar"
$formA.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 300,100

#Création d'un label (Label).
$labelA1 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
$labelA1.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 20,12
$labelA1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,16)
$labelA1.text = "Traitement en cours ..."

#Barre de progression (Progress bar).
$progressA1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$progressA1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Point 20,32
$progressA1.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(250,23)
$syncHash.ProgressBar.Value
$progressA1.Step()
#Timer.
#Le timer va me permettre de lancer automatiquement le traitement 
#1 seconde après l'ouverture de la fenêtre.
$timer1 = new-object System.Windows.forms.timer
$timer1.Interval = 1000   #Initialement je lance le timer au bout d'une seconde.
$timer1.Enabled  = $true
$timer1.add_Tick({
                               #Initialisation.
                               #Pour éviter de lancer 2 fois le traitement je change
                               # l'intervalle d'exécution du timer.
                               $timer1.Interval = 999999

                   
                                  #Force l'exécution des events de la fenêtre.
                                  [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()

                                  #Mise à jour de la bar de progression.
                                  $progressA1.PerformStep()
                      sleep -Milliseconds 500

                 })

#Attache les contrôles à la fenêtre.
$formA.controls.add($labelA1)
$formA.controls.add($progressA1)

#Lance le timer.
$timer1.Start()

#Affiche fenêtre.
$formA.ShowDialog()
$timer1.Stop()
$formA.Close()
})
$psCmd.Runspace = $processRunspace
$data = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
```

I'm wonder if the problem is not one of them :

**$syncHash.ProgressBar.Value** or
**$progressA1.Step()**

The variable **$NewMultiThreadprogress** is supposed to be a value from a function, i can specify a number who create progress bar at % number that i define.

Comment: Anytime I see this come up I like to refer people to FoxDeploy's guide on threading [here](https://www.foxdeploy.com/blog/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars.html). He actually specifically talks about creating a responsive app with a progress bar.

Comment: Thanks, i'll watch your link